# How to get a list of commits related to a specific release?

Tags: git, github

I need to get a list of commits between two releases of a library from a git repository. Let's suppose we have the following releases:

```
3.0 (4 commits since 2.11)
2.11 (12 commits since 2.10)
2.10 (20 commits since 2.9)
2.9 (and so on...)
```

I want to do something like:

```
git log -release "3.0"
```

then output the 4 commits hashes here associated with release 3.0

```
"cef7992412382bfb0a48d7a4c853a968e5489f81"
"1e9fe06192d96b298007d050628e853340ea9548"
"a5ef456d556beab241a8071b08139b148858fb34"
"4e0d434429356798e5d9c7e576a930df6bbd6a97"
```

What I suspect is that this can be done through tags, since new releases is annotated with tags... but i have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a linear history, the list of commits between 2.11 and 3.0 would simply be:

```
git log 2.11..3.0
```

If you just want the count of commits, that would be something like:

```
git log --oneline 2.11..3.0 | wc -l
```

Comment: You do not need to assume linear history, you can read it as: "display all commits reachable by 3.0 that are not reachable by 2.11"

Comment: For a non-linear history (e.g., 3.0 was branched from 2.9), I wasn't sure the result would be meaningful for this use case.  Maybe it would; I haven't fully thought that part through.

Comment: Perhaps not, but probably worth mentioning how it behaves on a non-linear history because it is easy to confuse the human concept of since (time-based) with the git concept of since (ancestry-based). We actually leverage this working with both linear and non-linear histories in our automated script that generates our release notes. It would also be fairly trivial to create an alias that accepts a commitish and automatically looks up the previous release.

Comment: @LightBender can you point me some link about time-based vs ancestry-based, I need to get good understanding about this at log level. I want to track down the evolution history of a project based on release version.

Comment: @Maigret It isn't so much an official concept as a common roadblock I run into when teaching git. In short, humans think of "since 2.11" to mean "since last Tuesday" or whenever 2.11 was created. Git looks at it differently, it translates 2.11 and 3.0 into their hashes then compares their ancestral relationships. Time is not a factor. The confusion, as larsks correctly pointed out, is that many of these commits may have taken place chronologically before v2.11, even though they were logically added after it in git's history (from your current vantage point).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log "--pretty=%h %D"` (for instance) to get a log of commits with their refs, then pipe it through a script like this (here in Python 3.x) to group the list of commits per the last (newest) tag encountered.

```py
import sys
import collections

last_tag = None
commits_per_tag = collections.defaultdict(set)


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    commit, _, refs = line.partition(" ")
    if refs.startswith("tag:"):
        last_tag = refs.split(", ")[0]
    commits_per_tag[last_tag].add(commit)


for last_tag, commits in sorted(
    commits_per_tag.items(),
    key=lambda pair: len(pair[1]),
    reverse=True,
):
    print(last_tag, len(commits))
```

For example, with [babel](https://github.com/python-babel/babel), the results are:

```
$ git log "--pretty=%h %D" | python3 so54787120.py

tag: 1.0 708
tag: 2.3.1 125
tag: dev-2a51c9b95d06 118
tag: v2.4.0 72
tag: 2.0 66
tag: v2.6.0 44
tag: 2.2.0 37
None 32
tag: 2.3.4 25
tag: v2.5.0 23
tag: 1.2 19
tag: v2.5.2 18
tag: 1.1 14
tag: 1.3 13
tag: 2.3.2 11
tag: v2.5.1 6
tag: v2.5.3 5
```

Your mileage may vary depending on the linearity of your history.

Comment: nice script. it's possible to show a list of all commits hashes for each tag?

Comment: Yes – replace `len(commits)` with `commits`.